# How to install Jflex on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: java, macos, jflex

I've spent the last 3 hours trying to follow the instructions on the **http://jflex.de/installing.html** page.

So far I have tried:

- to move the jflex-1.6.1 file to the hidden `usr/shared` folder (which is not permitted)
- and moving the jflex-1.6.1 file to a developer folder I have in my home directory, and then creating a symbolic link using the code `ln -s /developer/jflex-1.6.1/bin/jflex /usr/bin/jflex`, which is also not permitted.

I know that with the Sierra Os there is a lot of new restrictions on programs being downloaded from unrecognized developers, so I even edited the restrictions to allow any programs using the code `sudo spctl --master-disable` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "usr/local/bin/jflex instead of usr/bin/jflex" or disable the System Integrity Protection. Type "csrutil status" in your terminal to check it.